# Creating .dll file without null characters

Tags: dll, minify, portable-executable

Is there any way to design small and simple dll file, that after compiling won't contain any 0x00 character?

There are a few projects like tinyPE, but they are focused on size not on the target file.

Comment: _' that after compiling won't contain any 0x00 character?'_ Huh, what?!?

Comment: That does not appear to be possible, no. Why would you want to?

Comment: It's unclear why you are trying to do this. Perhaps provide more information and we can assist with solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If a DLL file contains string constants, those strings need to end with a `null` byte anyway. You can't prevent a `null` byte from appearing in a DLL. Each byte is put in a DLL for a reason.

Comment: You could work around that by encoding the whole data segment and decoding it on DLL-load.

Comment: @athreoz Even an encoded DLL will contain `null` characters. The string constants was just an example of why `null` characters are needed in DLLs.

Comment: @athreoz Is this some _realistic_ scenario, and worth doing so?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't think so.

Comment: @athreoz _'I don't think so.'_ dito!

Comment: @BennoZeeman: I'm aware of that, I was just clarifying that this is not actually the main problem.

Comment: I don't think I would need any string constant in it. I just want it to start, thats all.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many fields in the PE-header that just HAVE to contain 0-bytes to be valid to make this work. For example the `ImageBase` field in the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` is required to be a multiple of 64k, or Windows will refuse to load your binary. Also consider file addresses in the header: your file must be HUGE to not contain zeros in 32-bit (or even 64-bit on AMD64) file addresses.